# push segue not showing my detail page

Tags: iphone, push, segue

I have a tableview with about 10 items.

I have set up a UIView Controller as a detail page.

I Control-Drag from my cell in the tableview to the new view controller, and I can create a Push Segue, however the navigation control does not appear on the new view controller.

When I run the application my prepareForSegue method executes but my application does nothing. The detail UIView Controller does not display.

What step am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Push segue only makes sense for ViewControllers embedded inside a UINavigationController. You can do this easily by selecting your tableview's ViewController in the storyboard and choosing in the main menu:

Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

Comment: I did this. Now I can add the push segue and the navigation controller is added for the detail page. However, I run the application, and now when I select an item from the table the prepareForSegue method is not even executed and my app does not navigate to the detail UIViewController. I'm still missing something.

Comment: It seems that this is now working after I set the proper CellIdentifier.